# Calculated Column with Item ID not working for new Items

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

My calculated column is using the Item Name and Item ID

> ="list-name/"&Title&"/"&ID

This works for all existing items but when I create a new item the item ID is not being appended. Is this because the column is calculating before the item is created? If so, Is there a way to recalculate the column after the item is created?

If I can't use Item ID, is there another unique identifier i could use?

Comment: If can't use Item ID then I'm looking for some other unique identifier I can use.

Comment: None that would be usable in a calculated column. You can use ID, it just has to be done in a workflow, it does the same thing, string concatenation, and sets a field value as noted in the many similar questions revolving around this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported by Microsoft to use ID in a calculated column. That is the reason why does not appear in the options to build the formula.

Answer (score 3):

jpussacq is correct as to why it doesn't work.

You can workaround this by populating the field using a workflow. If the Title could be changed, the workflow should run when the item is created and when it is changed.

Comment: thank you but the title can't change. would you know another unique identifier i could use?

Comment: You can just write a workflow that sets a single line of text field to `list-name/[Current Item:Title]/[Current Item:ID]`.  Whether or not people can change the title only changes whether you need to run the workflow every time an item is edited.